# How do I model switches in Matlab/Simulink?

Tags: digital-logic, matlab, latch, simulink

I am trying to model different types of switches in Matlab/Simulink. There is this type of switch that I can't find a name for or design. I am not an expert in digital logic, I only have the basics from engineering school. The only input I have is this picture. Is there a name for this type of switch? If not, where can I start modeling these with logic gates in Simulink?

[image]

Comment: I don't have Matlab but, as I recall, you should have the basic math blocks which allow boolean logic. In rest, Karnaugh & co. Try Logisim (evolution), or Digital, both have a nifty tool for that.

Comment: That's called a T flip-flop. This one's output seems to have some dead time added, which is unusual.

Comment: Yes, I came across the T-Flip Flop in my research. But in my case I don't have Clk as input, I only have the pulse. I asked my supervisor again if he is sure that there is no Clk as input and the answer was that we don't have Clk as input. I did further research and there is no T "Latch".